# How to Execute Dynamic Sql String as a Query in mysql server?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have create a trigger which is create a dynamic query.and execute it i had tried 'EXECU q' but it does not work. how can i run/execute that dynamic query.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE q VARCHAR(500);

    SET q = 'insert into '+new.master_name+' values(';

    simple_loop: LOOP
        SET a=a+1; 
        SET str = SPLIT_STRING(new.remarks,"|",a); 
        SET q = CONCAT(q,str+',');
        SET q = LEFT(q, LENGTH(q) - 1);
        IF str='' THEN
                LEAVE simple_loop; 
            END IF;


    END LOOP simple_loop; 
    SET q = CONCATE(q,');');

    EXEC q
END
```

This is Trigerr
this is Function which i made
    RETURN REPLACE(
    SUBSTRING(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(str , delim , pos) ,
        CHAR_LENGTH(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(str , delim , pos - 1)
        ) + 1
    ) ,
    delim ,
    ''
)

Comment: use prepare statement

Comment: You should add the split_string function (which I don't think works)

Comment: i have add function which i made

Comment: That's not going to work dynamic sql is not allowed in a trigger or stored function.

Comment: what the option for if

Answer (score 5):

I've written a stored procedure to execute dynamically constructed sql statements.

## Usage

```
SET @index := 7;
CALL eval(CONCAT('SELECT ', @index));
```

---

## Implementation

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE eval(IN dynamic_statement TEXT)
  BEGIN
      SET @dynamic_statement := dynamic_statement;
      PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
      EXECUTE prepared_statement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
  END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you must make a prepared statement from your string first in order to execute it. So the following partial code should work in replacement for just `EXEC q`:

```
PREPARE thequery FROM q;
EXECUTE thequery;
```

Comment: i have tried this also but it does not work. give error at PREPARE thequery FROM q;

Answer (score 0):

use prepare statement to execute your dynamic query

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE q VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE q1 VARCHAR(500);
    DECLARE q2 VARCHAR(500);

    SET @q = 'insert into '+new.master_name+' values(';

    simple_loop: LOOP
        SET a=a+1; 
        SET str = SPLIT_STRING(new.remarks,"|",a); 
        SET q = CONCAT(@q,str+',');
        SET q1 = LEFT(q, LENGTH(q) - 1);
        IF str='' THEN
                LEAVE simple_loop; 
            END IF;


    END LOOP simple_loop; 

    SET q2 = CONCATE(q1,');');
    PREPARE stmt FROM q2;
    EXECecute stmt;
    deallocate PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: is dynamic sql is work in trigger or store producer ?

Comment: i have made changes ...try them

Comment: Still its will not allow at line PREPARE stmt FRom q2

Comment: What the meaning of @ notation? when we use it