# MySQL - INSERT INTO SELECT using subqueries for the column names and values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

Here's a question simple to solve in many other ways in the example I expose but in the real deal, my subqueries are more complex, but the principle to solve my own problem would be the same. A syntax problem most likely, so I reduced the problem to its simplest form.

Suppose I got the following tables:

```
/* contents_table */
  id │ field1   field3
 ════╪════════════════════ 
  1  │ os       devices_os


/* os_table */
  id │ devices_os  
 ════╪════════════ 
  1  │ android     
  2  │ ios         


/* my_table */
  id │ os       
 ════╪═════════ 
     │
```

`contentsTable.field1` holds the name of the column I need to set in `MyTable`,  `contentsTable.field2` holds the name of the column in `os_table` where I need the values to be taken.
If I do this the traditional way this is not a problem, as this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (os)
SELECT 'devices_os'
FROM os_table
```

Will fill `my_table` as I need:

```
/* my_table */
  id │ os       
 ════╪═════════ 
  1  │ android  
  2  | ios
```

What I need to do is accomplish this same result but using subqueries. Using this same example, here are some erroneous attempts:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (SELECT field1 FROM contents_table)
SELECT (SELECT field2 FROM contents_table)
FROM os_table;


INSERT my_table (SELECT field1 FROM contents_table)
VALUES (SELECT field2 FROM contents_table)
FROM os_table;


INSERT INTO my_table SELECT CONCAT('(', '(SELECT field1 FROM contents_table)', ')')
SELECT (    SELECT CONCAT('`', '(SELECT field2 FROM contents_table)', '`')    )
FROM os_table;
```

Seems possible but I can't figure it out.
Please enlighten me!

Comment: Seems possible, but it isn't. You have to put actual column names there. You could of course build up a query based on the results of another query, but those are separate steps: Query the columns, build an SQL string for the insert statement, execute that statement.

Comment: Depending on your environment there are different ways to do that (in MySQL, or in the client script/application), but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50580965/511529) shows it in a MySQL stored proc.

Comment: @GolezTrol That question/answer is unclear to me, and now with my question closed I don't understand what to do next.......